# The indicator in the carousel don't work, the slide effect is also not working

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I have been trying to display some images using carousel in HTML but the controls or indicators are not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IEEE MIT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-----------Navigation Bar----------------->
        <section id="nav-bar">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Ieee_logo.png"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">EVENTS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR TEAM</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    </section>

<!------------------Slider------------->
<div id="slider">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="council.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="IEEE_connect.png" class="d-block w-100" >
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="slide2.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="projects.png" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing div 'id', making other image div active. The only difference i could have generated is activating all the images together which are displayed overlapped on each other.

Comment: One code smell, you're including bootstrap js before the jQuery js

Comment: Do you still have issues after resolving that?

Comment: No, your suggestion helped me fix it sorry to reply late. Thank you once again